# Classification for high dimension data

Tags: machine-learning, classification, data-transformation, dataset, high-dimensional

Given a dataset of very large dimension `> 1000`, what would be the suitable classification algorithm that can handle such large dimensionality of data, assuming dimensionality reduction is not allowed in my dataset?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Many features leads to high variance --overfitting occurs.  With so many dimensions, the model is bound to find chance associations.

Popular methods to reduce overfitting include

- regularization aka penalizatiom aka shrinkage.  Eg lasso, ridge, elastic net.
- bagging, eg random forest
- dropout, augmentation
- boosting, eg adaboost, xgboost

These all work either as classifiers (output probabilities) or regressors